# Pointer to second base object

Tags: c++, oop

I read in book that, if you point a base pointer to a derived object and then increment the pointer, it will not be pointing to the next derived object. It will be pointing to the next base object. But how? I tried something given below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Base{
    int x;
    public:
        void setx(int x){
            this->x = x;
        }
        int getx(){
            return x;
        }
};

class Derived : public Base{
    int y;
    public:
        void sety(int y){
            this->y = y;
        }

        int gety(){
            return y;
        }
};


int main()
{
Base *p;// pointer to base type

Base base_object; // object of base
Derived derived_object;
Base secondBaseObj;


//use p to access the base object

p = &base_object;
p->setx(10);
cout << "Base object value of x: "<< p->getx()<<endl;
base_object.setx(100);
cout << "Base object value of x: "<< p->getx()<<endl;

p->setx(20);
cout << "Base object value of x: "<< base_object.getx()<<endl;




p = &derived_object;
derived_object.sety(15);
//cout << "Derived object value of y: "<< p->gety()<<endl;
//although base pointer can be used to point a derived object, you can access only those members
// of the derived object that are inherited from the base class;


p = p+1;
secondBaseObj.setx(30);
cout << "SecBase object value of x: "<< p->getx()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Base object value of x:10
Base object value of x:100
Base object value of x:20
SecBase object value of x:15
```

I increased the pointer by 1 and i called the `gex()` function but it returned the value of derived class `gety()` function.

Comment: This kind of pointer arithmetic works with arrays, where the objects are guaranteed to come one after another. What you're doing, however, is undefined behavior. The way the parameters are on the stack, doing this might make the pointer point to a different variable on the stack, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: The book should be correct. However, to get the behaviour you want, the objects need to be stored directly after one another, which they aren't. Try a vector instead!

Answer (score 2):

You might be misunderstanding the book. The idea behind incrementing pointers is that **when objects are contiguous**, incrementing a pointer will make the pointer point to the next object.

But when are objects contiguous? The general rule is that two objects are not contiguous, unless the Standard says otherwise. And those cases are fairly limited: normal arrays `T[N]`, `std::vector<T>`, `std::array<T,N>`, `std::basic_string<Ch>`, `std::valarray<T>` (with qualifications), and `std::complex<T>`.

In all these cases, the `T` objects are contiguous, but their bases are not.

Answer (score 0):

When you doing `p = p + 1;` compiler assumes that you are accessing elements of array, i.e. that before this there was something like:

```
Base storage[2];
Base *p = storage;
```

Even if you declare storage as `Derived storage[2];` compiler lose this information when you assign pointer to different type.

And what you are doing, i.e. accessing incremented pointer that is pointing to single object is undefined behavior. Since there is no any guarantee what is located after your object in memory.